# Do you need a separate .swift file for each view controller in an app?

Tags: ios, swift

This is a very beginner question as I am new to the swift language and working on my first app.  I have been working in the default View Controller, which allows me to create outlets in the ViewController.swift file.  but when I create a new view controller I am unable to attach outlets to the ViewController.swift file.  so do I have to add a new .swift file for each view controller I add to the project?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you start with a tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/114148/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-1-welcome-to-programming

Comment: Actually no, however it's highly recommended. The classes must be distinctly separated, the physical file doesn't matter as long as it's in the same namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign to your new controller in the storyboard a class (inside a `.swift` file), but you can have multiple controllers with the same class, just add a class to your controller here :

[image]

Example :

If you have a `Test.swift` like this :

```
//Test.swift
class viewController1: UIViewController {
}

class viewController2: UIViewController {
}
```

You could assign `viewController1` or `viewController2` inside your storyboard to your ViewController, however you should always have a single subclass of `UIViewController` inside your `.swift` file.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely. Best practice is a separate file for each View Controller and other major classes.

Refer to this [awesome free course from Stanford](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099) for a very nice introduction on MVC (Model-View-Controller).